# Oracle: Find control characters except line feed

Tags: oracle, linefeed, control-characters, regexp-like

I'm trying to all rows where a column contains any control charters with the exception of the line feed character (hex value of A). I've tried the following, but this only returns results that have a control character and don't have a line feed. I really want the set of characters that are control characters, LESS the line feed character. Is there a 'minus' operation for character sets, where you can exclude particular ones from it?

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(MyColumn, '[:cntrl: &&[^' || UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(HEXTORAW('A')) || ']]{1,}');
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well here's a first try that will work but I'm sure this can be made more elegant and efficient:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE regexp_like(MyColumn, '[[:cntrl:]]')
AND MyColumn NOT like '%' || chr(10) || '%';
```

Comment: This would in effect do the same thing as the query above, results would be only be returned when there is a control character and there is no instance of the line feed character. What I need is to find the results of all control characters, for the exception of the line feed character.